# Добавление фото в поиске гугл возле своего сайта

Tags: google-search

Как это сделать. В интернете все статьи 2014 года в которых говорится, что способ реализовать это через Google+ не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, Google перестает поддерживать функцию указания авторства в результатах выдачи. Фотография, а также другая информация об авторе в ближайшее время перестанет отображаться в расширенных сниппетах к статьям в SERP. Эту новость сообщил сотрудник поискового гиганта Джон Мюллер на странице в Google+: "мы пришли к выводу, что данная информация в результатах выдачи не несёт никакой практической выгоды нашим пользователям и даже отвлекает их от работы с результатами выдачи" (C) 2014 год